# changing the color of scroll bar?

Tags: css, scrollbar

In a div I gave overflow auto to have a scroll bar to display the content that exceeds the limit 
My scroll bar appears in blue color that doesn't suit my layout how can i change the color

```
div#navigation{background:#efe9b9; overflow:auto}
```

This is the css i am using ... I want brown colored scrll bar
How to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in IE, but I think it's been deprecated (or removed in IE8).

[You can also do it in Safari.](http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/)

Be warned that it will affect usability negatively.

Comment: are you  saying  that some time it work wrong

Comment: @udaya I am saying that a typical user may be confused by the scrollbar if it is a different colour than standard.

Answer (score 3):

(except in IE)You can't change Scrollbars with CSS only, check out the [JScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) for a Cross browser compatible scrollbar changer.

Comment: Actually, you can, but only in IE.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about IE, conveniently.

Comment: @deceze: [webkit supports scrollbar styling](http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html) (view in Chrome/Safari), too, although in a much better manner than IE.

Comment: @Andy's Oh, cute. Now I can detest two browsers for messing with standard UI elements. ;)

Comment: It is cross browser compatible, so yes, it will work.

@Andy E's Head: I didn't know that.

Comment: @Kyle whats the solution

Comment: @udaya: Did you look at the link I gave you? That's a jQuery plugin to enable you to change the appearance of scrollbars in a cross brwoser compatible way..